# Wierd code affects markup .net 6 razor page styles after publish

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I've have made a .net 6 web app.

I just published the site on a server:

But suddenly noticed the style of some a attributes have changed.

For example the footer is much larger:

I checked chrome devTools and there seems to be a number added to the attribute:

My local footer attribute looks like:

```
    <footer class="bg-dark footer text-muted mt-auto">
        <div class="container text-center">
            © 2022 - LTPWeb - Support: <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com">test@gmail.com</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

but on the server the footer attribute looks like:

```
    <footer b-jthj6vf6tt="" class="bg-dark footer text-muted mt-auto">
        <div b-jthj6vf6tt="" class="container text-center">
            © 2022 - LTPWeb - Support: <a b-jthj6vf6tt="" href="mailto:test@gmail.com">test@gmail.com</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Suddenly this code **b-jthj6vf6tt** is added:

If i remove this code the style is normal.

Is this just a bug or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is injected as part of the new CSS Isolation feature that was added in .NET 6: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/355/css-isolation-in-razor-pages

To opt out of this feature, move any styles you want to keep from the *_Layout.cshtml.css* file (in the *Shared* folder - it might be nested in VS Solution Explorer) to the *wwwroot/css/site.js* file and delete the *_Layout.cshtml.css* file. Then remove the `link` element in the `head` of the *Layout.cshtml* file that references *[YourAppName].styles.css*.